# How to find instances that DONT have a tag using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to find instances that DONT have a certain tag.

For instance I want all instances that don't have the Foo tag.
I also want instances that don't have the Foo value equal to Bar.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
import boto3


def aws_get_instances_by_name(name):
    """Get EC2 instances by name"""
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

    instance_iterator = ec2.instances.filter(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'tag:Name',
                'Values': [
                    name,
                ]
            },
            {
                'Name': 'tag:Foo',
                'Values': [

                ]
            },
        ]
    )

    return instance_iterator
```

This is returning nothing.

What is the correct way?

Comment: There is no filter for negative comparison. You have to loop through all instances and check the tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's some code that will display the `instance_id` for instances **without** a particular tag:

```
import boto3

instances = [i for i in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2').instances.all()]

# Print instance_id of instances that do not have a Tag of Key='Foo'
for i in instances:
  if i.tags is not None and 'Foo' not in [t['Key'] for t in i.tags]:
    print i.instance_id
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks :) Although I'm a little disappointed negations do not work in filters.